# Dynamically generate aspx pages based on xml content files and a master page

Tags: asp.net, routes

I want to develop a web application with a master page containing an `<asp:Xml />` control for rendering xhtml content stored in xml files.

I can do this easily enough by creating a WebContent aspx page per xml file, but what I want to know is how to go about developing a single request handler which will detect a request for a page e.g. www.mysite.com/HomePage.aspx then generate a page based on the master page and assume that a corresponding xml content file exists (e.g. HomePage.xml).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to tackle this in a different way...

I'm using [UrlRewritingNet](http://www.urlrewriting.net/149/en/home.html) to handle requests for pages and have a single page (ShowPage.aspx) which loads the appropriate xml content file depending on a url parameter.
So if the page `www.mysite.com/about-us.aspx` is requested, this is handled by `www.mysite.com/ShowPage.aspx?PageName=about-us` and inside `ShowPage.aspx` I have code as follows:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string xmlFile = "~/" + Request["PageName"] + ".xml";
    xmlContent.DocumentSource = xmlFile;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the flow for this process. 
 - use a http module. module gets
 - request get requested page name and find xls file. 
 - populate xsl file data as xml.
 - merge xml and xls.
 - send response to client.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you be a bit more specific than 'use a http module'.